# Using PCM format of AWS Polly

Tags: aws-lambda, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I am trying to use AWS Polly (for TTS) using JavaScript SDK from AWS lambda (which is exposed through a REST API using API gateway). There is no trouble in getting the PCM output. Here is a call flow in brief.

> .NET application --> REST API (API gateway) --> AWS Lambda (JS SDK) --> AWS Polly

The .NET application (am using POSTMAN too for testing) gets an audio stream buffer in following format.

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255, more such data]
```

Now I don't know how to convert it back to raw PCM. I would like it send this data back as raw PCM but unable to find a way to do it. I also cannot understand why AWS would send data back in such a format. Using there console, one can get audio in raw PCM format (which I can then feed to Audacity), but not so simple with SDK. Or am I missing something really basic?

Any suggestions/tips on this? Thanks.

Comment: They aren't sending the data in a weird format.  This is what happens in Node when you coerce a binary [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object into JSON. It's binary content, and JSON can't handle arbitrary octets, only character data, so it becomes represented as an array of the binary byte values.  You'll likely need to base64-encode the original buffer in JS (to avoid this implicit conversion) and deliver them to API Gateway with the appropriate flag set, then they'll be decoded into the raw octets and returned to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That did the job. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to hear it.  Will you write up an answer, below, for the benefit of others who find your question in the future, including code snippets and any settings you needed to change?  (Please?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Michael mentioned (in the comment), sending the response from Polly back causes the stream to turn into a JSON object. Encoding the received buffer from Polly in base64 fixes this. Here's what code sample now looks like -

```
polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response

    //old code
    //callback(null, data.Audiostream); //this converts buffer to JSON obj
    //use below instead
    if (data && data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {

        var buf = data.AudioStream.toString('base64');
        callback(null, buf);
    }
});
```

PS: I am using AWS SDK on AWS lambda

Answer (score 0):

When making the request to amazon polly, set the OutputFormat to pcm, with that you don;t have to worry about any conversions like this;
const params = {
Text: message,
OutputFormat: "pcm",
VoiceId: "Joanna",
};

```
  polly?.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err: any, data: any) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err, err.stack);
    } else if (data.AudioStream) {
    // you audio stream will be here
      
    }
  });
```